# Os pseudo elementos ::after e ::before funcionam em quais elementos?

Tags: html, css3, pseudo-elementos

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma documentação ou artigo que diga onde exatamente podemos usar `::after` e `::before`

Já vi que na tag `<img>` por exemplo não funciona. Acredito que não funciona por que a `<img>` é um elemento do tipo **Void Element** (elemento que não tem uma tag de fechamanto).

Porém a tag **`<input>`** também é um Void Element, no entanto para certo types o ::after e ::before funcionam! *Eu sei que no `<label>` funciona e que jQuery pode tudo, mas essa não é a resposta que eu quero.*

```css
body {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
div {
   padding: 25px;
}
::after {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
#teste-button::after{
  content: 'after button';
}
#teste-text::after{
  content: 'after text';
}
#teste-radio::after{
  content: 'after radio';
}
#teste-checkbox::after{
  content: 'after checkbox';
}
#teste-password::after{
  content: 'after password';
}
#teste-submit::after{
  content: 'after submit';
}
#teste-range::after{
  content: 'after range';
}
#teste-file::after{
  content: 'after file';
}
#teste-textarea::after{
  content: 'after textarea';
}
#teste-btn::after{
  content: 'after btn';
}
#teste-img::after{
  content: 'after img';
}
#teste-legend::after{
  content: 'after legend';
}
#teste-label::after{
  content: 'after label';
}
#teste-img2::after{
  content: 'after type img';
}
```

```html
<div><input type="button" value="input button" id="teste-button" /></div>

<div><input type="text" value="type text" id="teste-text" /></div>

<div><input type="radio" value="teste" id="teste-radio" /></div>

<div><input type="checkbox" value="teste" id="teste-checkbox" /></div>

<div><input type="password" value="teste" id="teste-password" /></div>

<div><input type="submit" value="submit" id="teste-submit" /></div>

<div><input type="range" value="teste" id="teste-range" /></div>

<div><input type="file" name="file" placeholder="Arquivo" id="teste-file" /></div>

<div><textarea rows="2" cols="10" id="teste-range">textarea</textarea></div>

<div><button type="button" id="teste-btn">button</button></div>

<div><input type="image" alt="Login" id="teste-img2" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/learning-area/master/html/forms/image-type-example/login.png">input type="image" </div>

<div><img src='sem-img.jpg' id="teste-img" alt='img quebrada'/></div>

<div><img src='https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' id="teste-img" alt='img ok' style="width: 150px; height:auto"/>imagem ok</div>

<div><legend id="teste-legend">Legend</legend></div>

<div><label for="radio" id="teste-label">Label</label></div>
```

Fiz esse código rapidinho mesmo só pra mostrar o que estou falando. Reparem que parece não ter uma explicação onde funciona ou não.

Tentei achar uma lista de aplicação correta desses pseudo elements, porém nada muito certo... Alguém tem alguma explicação?

Comment: Acho que isso depende muito da implementação do navegador e não do HTML em si.

Comment: @Sveen acho que se fosse pelo browser teria after funcionando no IE e não no Chrome por exemplo, então se eh uma limitação do browser todos eles tem exatamente a mesma limitação, algo ate raro de ver... Mas quando pesquisei na época parece que o after não pega em elementos que não tem tag de fechamento, mas em um ou outro funciona, talvez pelo CSS do User agent, ou algum padrão do input determinado pela w3c... Vai saber rss

Comment: Puramente numa otica de contribuir para a pergunta, está [aqui](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content) a documentação oficial da  W3 nos pseudo seletores citados. Curiosamente a documentação é bem pequena, meio vaga e não menciona tipos de elementos afetados. A julgar por [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5843164/6087092) no SOen parece que está relacionado com o facto de alguns elementos não poderem ter texto como conteúdo.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Isac vou ler o material!

Answer (score 5):

Os pseudo elementos ::after e ::before não funcionam em *[replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) [(definição)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element)*. Estes elementos são definidos como aqueles que estão fora do escopo do CSS, como img, iframes, video, hr, br, embed e input.

O motivo disso é que o conteúdo inserido como before ou after é tratado como filho, não como irmão do conteúdo originário. Os elementos replaced não tem qualquer conteúdo na árvore do DOM e, por isso, não podem receber qualquer tipo de filho.

A questão dos **inputs** é mais difícil. Inputs com type image são replaced. O chrome aceita para alguns tipos de input (checkbox, radio, color, file, date, datetime-local, month, range, time, week), mas este comportamento não é consistente entre os browsers, não funcionando no Firefox, por exemplo. No dia-a-dia é melhor, ao menos por enquanto, incluir inputs na lista dos elementos que não recebem before ou after.

A [documentação da MDN sobre o before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) explica que elementos subtituídos ou "replaced elements" não aceitam essa tag e que a tag input às vezes é considerada "replaced" (fora do escopo do CSS). Há quem argumente que todos os inputs deveriam ser tratados como replaced, apenas o type="image" ou nenhum deles ([este artigo discute o tema](https://dzone.com/articles/css-tricks-generated-content)). [Lea Verou (tratando de outra questão)](http://lea.verou.me/page/5/) afirma que não se deve confiar em pseudo-elementos em elementos replaced, notadamente o input com type="checkbox" porque apesar de funcionar, não está especificado.

Comment: "pode não funcionar, dependendo do contexto" qual contexto? Pq eu não sei pq funciona no `checkbox` e não no `text` Se possível crie um exemplo diferente dos que eu já cite na pergunta, tipo colocando um `::after` direto em uma tag `input` do tipo `text` seria excelente. Eu fiz o teste e mesmo colocando display:block, altura e largura em uma caixa de texto não foi possível fazer o after ser reconhecido...  Os links que vc citou explicam o que é um *replaced element.* e o que é o before e after, mas não diz pq não funciona em uns inpunts e funciona em outros...

Comment: Interessante que não obstante a documentação afirmar que img e input com type image não recebem after e before, o Chrome exibe o after quando a imagem não é encontrada. A palavra contexto ficou realmente ruim. Não obtante, as regras explicam sim por que funciona em uns e não nos outros. Funciona nos elementos que não são replaced. Inputs às vezes são considerados replaced. Vou ajustar a resposta para se adequar melhor à pergunta.

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender por que text e textarea não exibem o before e o after. Acredito que o motivo pelo qual o type image não exibe é suficientemente claro. O button também. O before e o after fazem parte do elemento e se a renderização do conteúdo do elemento não está sob controle do CSS, então não há lugar para o before ou after.

Comment: A especificação ainda é meio "obscura", apesar de não ser preciso agora ficou melhor.

Comment: É... também acho. Parece que este tema ainda está em debate. Existem propostas para criar novos pseudo-elementos para atingir o objetivo de inserir conteúdo antes e depois de replaced elements. Na verdade fiquei surpreso que os outros navegadores não suportem before em checkboxes, já que ao menos para mim parece ser muito útil.  Parece-me que a abordagem do Chrome de tratar alguns tipos de input como não replaced me parece correta. Só não entendo por que não incluem nessa lista os inputs de texto.