# Não consigo inserir icone dentro de uma imagem com after ou before

Tags: html, scss

Preciso implementar um `icone` no `:after` desse campo de `radio` pois quero que fique parecido com o da imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] eu consegui inserir o `css` normal só não estou conseguindo implementar o icone que ficaria no canto esquerdo da tela oque estou fazendo de errado segue o código:

```
<li class="col-lg-3 col-xlg-2 ">
                                        <label class="label-image">
                                            <input class="input-image" type="radio" name="fb" value="small" />
                                            <img src="assets/images/covers/cover-01.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                                        </label>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="col-lg-3 col-xlg-2 ">
                                        <label class="label-image">
                                            <input class="input-image" type="radio" name="fb" value="small" />
                                            <img src="assets/images/covers/cover-02.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
```

SCSS:

```
.label-image > .input-image {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    + img {
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 5px solid transparent;
    }
    &:checked + img {
      border: 25px solid $white;
      position: relative;
      &:after{
          content: "\f00c";
          font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
          color: $white;
          font-size: 30px;
          background-color: $orange;
          border-radius: 100px;
          padding: 15px;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vc se refere a bolinha azul com um check no topo esquerdo das imagens?

Comment: @hugocsl isso mesmo nao estou conseguindo fazer elas aparecerem

Comment: @hugocsl alguma ideia do que pode ser ?

Comment: Vc está usando qual versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: @hugocsl a versão 4

Comment: Cara tem alguns detalhes que vou ter que mexer tb na estrutura do html... na ordem das tags etc... mas o principal do seu código não estar funcionando é pq vc não pode usar um ::after em uma tag `<img>` como vc pode ver aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263040/os-pseudo-elementos-after-e-before-funcionam-em-quais-input-types então vc tem que repensar a estrutura entende...