# O alvo de seletores CSS com pseudo-elemento ::before

Tags: css3, pseudo-elementos

Olá, estou estudando CSS3 e, num determinado tutorial, analisei todo ele, e não entendi o ponto em que o `::before` foi usado junto com o checkbox, no qual foi acrescentado a propriedade `content`.

Por que no primeiro uso do `::before` com a pseudo-clase `:checked` ele estiliza o valor de `content` e não estiliza o checkbox em si?

Segue código:

```css
body {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #262626;
}

#botoes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
}

#botoes input[type=checkbox]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  transition: .1s;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 15px #ffffff;
}

#botoes input[type=checkbox] {
  position: relative;
  background: #b9b9c8;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  outline: none;
}

#botoes input:checked[type=checkbox]::before {
  left: 40px;
}

#botoes input:checked[type=checkbox] {
  background: dodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>Test Toogle With Pure CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/xxxxxxxx.css">
</head>
<div class="box" id="box">
</div>

<body>
  <div id="botoes">
    Hidden Rings
    <input type="checkbox"> Collision Rings
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Você quer saber porque no `elemento::before` precisa colocar o `content` e no `elemento` em si não? Se é isso, é porque o `content` do elemento em si é definido no HTML, mas a tag `input` é um pouco diferente

Comment: Não, Guilherme, veja no 2º parágrafo da minha pergunta: por que o CSS estiliza o conteúdo do elemento (o content) e não o próprio elemento, entendeu? Veja todo o código css postado (com scrool), ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fernandes se eu te entendi bem vc quer saber porque ele usou o `content` correto?

**Vamos as explicações.**

> Um pseudo-elemento CSS é uma palavra-chave adicionada a um seletor que
>   permite que você estilize uma parte específica do elemento
>   selecionado.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos

> `::before` cria um *pseudo-elemento* que é o primeiro filho do
>   elemento atingido. É frequentemente utilizado para adicionar conteúdo
>   decorativo à um *element* utilizando a propriedade `content`. Este
>   elemento é `inline` por padrão.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Veja nessa imagem que quando o HTML e o CSS são renderizados na página é criado o *pseudo-elemento* dentro do `input`, que por sua vez ganha uma tag de fechamento adicionada pelo próprio browser. Como vc pode ver na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém esse comportamento dos *input types* (checkbox, radio, text, numeber, email, etc...) não é padrão, e não são todos os `inputs` que pode receber um *pseudo-elemento* `::after` e `::before` como vc pode ver nessa questão: [Os pseudo elementos ::after e ::before funcionam em quais input types](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263040/os-pseudo-elementos-after-e-before-funcionam-em-quais-input-types)

Perceba que no HTML temos apenas a tag `<input type="checkbox">` que corresponde ao fundo cinza do *switch-buttom* já o *toggle* que é a bolinha que vai de um lado para o outro ela "não existe" no HTML, ela é construída com o *pseudo-elemento*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E porque precisa colocar o `content:""` nos pseudo elementos?**

> A propriedade CSS `content` é usada com os *pseudo elementos* `::before` e
>   `::after` para gerar conteúdo em um elemento. Objetos inseridos usando a
>   propriedade `content` são *elementos substituídos* anônimos.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/content

*"No CSS existe a possibilidade de você inserir um elemento de mentira (pseudo-elemento) em objetos no HTML. Estes elementos pode te auxiliar em diversos momentos do desenvolvimento, prevenindo a criação de elementos HTML vazios para produzir algum detalhe do layout que possa se misturar com o conteúdo real. ... O mais legal é que você pode formatar com CSS os elementos ::after e ::before como se fossem elementos do HTML, usando as propriedades normais que já usamos diariamente."*

Esse artigo pode te ajudar a entender melhor o assunto: https://tableless.com.br/geracao-estatica-de-conteudo-via-css/

Uma pequena explicação direto no código:

```css
/* cor do btn sem estar checado "cinza" */
#botoes input[type=checkbox] {
  background: #b9b9c8;
}
/* cor do btn quando está checado "azul" */
#botoes input:checked[type=checkbox] {
  background: dodgerBlue;
}

/* quando vc declara um pseudo-elemento vc precisa declarar que ele tem um "conteúdo" (content) */
/* esse "conteúdo" antes de ser checado esta com left 0 */
#botoes input[type=checkbox]::before {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
}

/* depois de checado o "conteúdo" afasta 40px pra direita */
/* nesse momento vc não precisa declarar novamente o content, pois independe do input está checado ou não  o contente já foi declarado no ::before anteriormente */
#botoes input:checked[type=checkbox]::before {
  left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, hugocsl. Se entendi bem (confirme), quando eu declaro um pseudo-elemento com ::before e content, então, eu posso estilizar somente este content, também via ::before, é isto? Ou seja, na linha: #botoes input:checked[type=checkbox]::before eu estou dizendo para o CSS estilizar o conteúdo do input checkbox quando este for checado, e não o elemento input[type=checkbox], é isso?

Comment: PS: já pontuei a sua resposta. Muito detalhada. Muito grato!

Comment: @Fernandes fala jove, vou tentar simplificar. Imagina que vc tem 4 *estados* de css no mesmo elemento. Os 2 primeiros são `input` e `input:checked` onde vc tem o input com fundo cinza e depois input:checked com fundo azul. E os outros 2 sao o `input::before ` e o `input:checked::before`, onde antes do checked a bolinha fica de um lado, e depois do checked a bolinha fica do outro lado. Essa e a estrutura para vc montar se CSS. Agora sobre o `contet` é como eu falei na explicação, todo elemento ::after e ::before devem ter a propriedade `content=" "` para poder ser renderizado pelo browser

Comment: Vc pode ter um content vazio ou com algum conteúdo dentro tipo `content=" btn n. 1"`, mas colocar coisas dentro do contente não é obrigatório. Obrigatória apenas é colocar a propriedade `content=" "` no ::after ou ::before. `#botoes input[type=checkbox]::before {
  content: ''; }` sem o content o pseuto elemento não será "criado" no HTML. @Fernandes Quando tiver um tempinho de uma olhada no links que citei na resposta, vão te esclarecer muitas coisas

Comment: hugocsl, na boa, já entendi muito bem. Vc foi muito prático na resposta quando complementou observando, neste caso, que são quatro estados de css no mesmo elemento! De boa, entendi. Grato!

Comment: @Fernandes legal que ficou claro o que eh o que rss, as vezes isso eh meio confuso mesmo. Qualquer duvida eh só dar o toque, bons estudos!