# Como adicionar ícones antes do placeholder

Tags: html, css, input

Eu estou trabalhando no front de um login e estou querendo inserir os ícones de contato para o campo de e-mail e o de cadeado para o de senha. Quero inserir antes da mensagem do *placeholder*. Eu não estou utilizando Bootstrap. Teria como fazer isso com os seletor `::before`? e teria como também utilizar algo análogo ao `:nth-child()` na hora de passar o endereço desses ícones?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.login {
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 540px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #cc252f;
  position: relative;
}

.fields {
  margin: auto;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
}

.fields input {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 98%;
  height: 46%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <div class="fields">
    <input type="email" maxlength="30" name="email" id="email" placeholder="e-mail"><br>
    <input type="password" maxlength="16" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="senha">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Parabéns a sua pergunta foi uma das mais bem feitas que vi nas últimas semanas. Mas como vc pode ver aqui não é possível colocar um pseudo elemento direto no input https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263040/os-pseudo-elementos-after-e-before-funcionam-em-quais-input-types

Comment: O mínimo a ser feito quando se precisa de ajuda e deixar a pergunta o mais clara possível. Que bom que achou que ela ficou bem feita, a tendência aqui é melhorar. Abs!

Comment: Lucas o que vejo aqui é que a maioria quer ajuda, mas tem preguiça até de escrever uma pergunta com detalhes. Tem gente que chega a postar uma imagem e falar "Quero isso" e só. Sim sempre buscamos nos tornar melhor, por isso fiz uma edição na resposta haha. Abs 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma opção de ícone usando o FontAwesome no pseudo elemento da label não do input, pois o input não aceita pseudo elemento como vc pode ver no link que comentei acima. Aqui vc pode conferir os demais ícones https://fontawesome.com/

Vc pode usar `nth-child(3)`, mas tem que ser `3` pq tem um elemento `BR` entre um `input` e outro. Mas repare que só no `content=""` do `::after` eu mudei de um ícone para o outro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código da imagem acima:

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.login {
 margin: auto;
 width: 350px;
 height: 540px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 background-color: #cc252f;
 position: relative;
}

.fields {
 margin: auto;
 width: 240px;
 height: 100px;
}

.fields input {
 font-size: 1em;
 width: 98%;
 height: 46%;
 margin-top: 2px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-left: 30px;
}
label {
 position: relative;
}
label::after {
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 float: left;
 margin-left: -1.5em;
 content: "\f007";
 color: #000;

 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
}
label:nth-child(3)::after {
 content: "\f13e";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="login">
 <div class="fields">
  <label><input type="email" maxlength="30" name="email" id="email" placeholder="e-mail"></label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="password" maxlength="16" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="senha"></label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma bacana é usar uma imagem como sprite (pode ser um PNG com fundo transparente, um GIF ou um JPG com fundo branco). Aí basta adicionar a imagem como background do input posicionando cada ícone do sprite no respectivo input.

No exemplo abaixo usei a imagem abaixo com formato PNG, com as dimensões de 33x100 pixels:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É preciso que a imagem seja vertical e tenha uma altura par onde cada ícone será centralizado verticalmente em cada metade, ou seja, 50px.

No CSS você posiciona cada ícone nos eixos X e Y. No caso do eixo X (horizontal) eu dei um espaçamento de 10px para não colar na borda do input, e no input do password eu posicionei -40px (metade) para que o background suba mostrando o segundo ícone. E também usei um `padding-left` nos inputs para que o texto não fique por cima dos ícones, compensando a largura dos ícones.

Também é preciso ajustar o `width` dos inputs para deduzir o `padding-left` aplicado. Para isso você usa o `calc`, subtraindo a largura dos inputs pelo `padding-left` aplicado:

```
width: calc(98% - 48px);
```

Analisando o CSS você vai entender como funciona e o resultado:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.login {
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 540px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #cc252f;
  position: relative;
}

.fields {
  margin: auto;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100px;
}

.fields input {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: calc(98% - 48px);
  height: 46%;
  padding-left: 48px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px;
}

#email, #pwd{
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqyJ8.png) #fff no-repeat;
}

#email{
   background-position: 10px 12px;
}

#pwd{
   background-position: 10px -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <div class="fields">
    <input type="email" maxlength="30" name="email" id="email" placeholder="e-mail"><br>
    <input type="password" maxlength="16" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="senha">
  </div>
</div>
```